# How to fetch data into a textview?

Tags: java, android, textview

This is my code to fetch database values into the `listview`.

```
private void fetchData2() {
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(DBhelper.TABLE2, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.row2,
                c,
                new String[]{DBhelper.Amount},
                new int[]{R.id.lbl});
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I just want to change this code to get the values into **a textview**,

Comment: Which value want to show in TextView?

Comment: loop through Cursor, and extract data into String. Then set this string to textview

Comment: DBhelper.Amount I want to show this in my textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this...

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){

String data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Column's Index"));

yourTextView.setText(data);

}
```